# Checking value in database on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an href in my asp.net MVC3 Razor view and I want to check on click of this razor view:

If there exist a record in database, If exists, then show alert, otherwise print some value on page.

link html is like this:

```
<a class="orphan item subtext" href="#" id="lnkfreereport">
    <span>
       Order Your Free Report
    </span>
</a>
```

Please suggest how can I do this using asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer AjaxHelper class ActionLink method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

AJAX?

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Order Your Free Report", 
    "CheckExists", 
    "SomeControllerName",
    null,
    new { id = "checkExists" }
)
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#checkExists').click(function() {
        $.getJSON(this.href, function(result) {
            if (result) {
               alert('the record exists');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and then you could have a controller action which checks whether the given record exists and returns JSON:

```
public ActionResult CheckExists() 
{
    bool exists = ...
    return Json(exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @Drain: where should i put this javascript file and where should i give its path ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, you put it in a separate javascript file in your Scripts folder and then you reference it like this on your page: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: I tried the  return Json(exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); in action method and when i run and click the link, It says, "Do you want to open or save CheckExists (4 bytes from localhost)"

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, did you notice the `return false` at the end of my .click handler? This will cancel the default action of the anchor which is a standard redirect and perform the AJAX request. Also make sure that you have referenced jQuery and that the generated HTML for the anchor looks something like this: `<a href="/SomeControllerName/CheckExists" id="checkExists">Order Your Free Report</a>`. Also make sure that the script you have included is properly found.

Comment: I have added that even then I am getting this

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, is the custom javascript file you have included properly referenced? Look at the Net tab in FireBug. You will see all HTTP requests. There shouldn't be any 404 errors. That's some really basic javascript work that is independent of ASP.NET MVC and that you should be aware of.

Comment: I see that file is located and referenced properly and href also looks fine but still getting same error.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1318/discussion-between-dotnetsparrow-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, did you manage to get this working? Email me your source code if you want so that I can take a look at what's wrong.

Comment: whats your email :( I am stuck for last 6 hours

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, it's `darin[DOT]dimitrov[AT]gmail[DOT]com`.

Comment: just emailed. Thanks in advance. Waiting... Fingers crossed